# no module name, underscore import

Tags: python, python-3.x

Try to run a python app through command line like `python -m myapp.start --config <myFile>`.

Got exception

```
    from awscrt import mqtt
  File "/Myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awscrt/mqtt.py", line 14, in <module>
    import _awscrt
ImportError: No module named '_awscrt'
```

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-python/blob/master/awscrt/mqtt.py#L14

Really not a python guy, any idea or resolution? BTW, I am using python 3.5.

Comment: Did you PIP install the library awscrt ?

Comment: Do you have multiple version of Python installed? It looks like the `awscrt` package from a Python 3.6 installation is being used.

Comment: Command prompt and type pip install awscrt

Comment: @Brian does different package will has its dedicated python version to run? Like `awscrt` will have different version for python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7?

Comment: Brian means that the Python version you used to install a module, should be the same Python version you use to run your app/script. If awscrt was installed in Python3.5, then you need to also use Python3.5 to run your app. You seem to have used Python3.6 to run your app/script, but awscrt is not installed there.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you have the module for the correct version try:

```
python -m pip install awscrt
```

This will guarantee that the pip version matches the current python version you are trying to run the app with.

Comment: `c4b301cf95ad:.runtimes user$ python -m pip install awscrt
Requirement already satisfied: awscrt in /Myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ (0.5.2)`

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled over a similar error and blogged about it [here](https://carl.duevel.online/blog/python_missing_system_deps/). Basically the underscore in the module name shows that it [is a module written in C or C++](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names). The reason it is missing from your system is most likely missing system dependencies during installation. Those vary by platform. The [setup.py](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-python/blob/c4502865e4837625f3aada072df06b24d17569d8/setup.py#L237) seems to be a good place find those needed for your system. After installation of those dependencies awscrt has to be removed and installed again.